# Zeller's Algorithm with Tkinter Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

The code below is written to print out the day of the date wirtten which is called zellers algorithm. I tried to compile it with Tkinter but I get errors everytime.What is wrong with my code I would be glad if someone helps me. Error is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Ali/Desktop/zellers­revisited.py", line 60, in <lambda>
    button = Tkinter.Button(zeller, text = "Show the day",command = lambda:zellers(A,B,C) )
  File "C:/Users/Ali/Desktop/zellers­revisited.py", line 11, in zellers
    D = int(str(C)[0:2])+1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

import math
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox

dictionary = {"March": 1, "April":2, "May":3, "June":4, "July":5,"August":6, "September":7, "October":8, "November":9, "December":10 ,"January":11, "February":12}
def zellers(a,b,c):
    a = int(str(c)[0:2])+1
    a = int(dictionary[a])
    a = int(str(c)[2:4])    
    w = ((13*a)-1) / 5
    x = c / 4
    y = d / 4
    z = (w + x + y + b + c) - 2*d
    r = z%7
    if r == 0:
        print "Sunday"
    elif r == 1:
        print "Monday"
    elif r == 2:
        print "Tuesday"
    elif r == 3:
        print "Wednesday"
    elif r == 4:
        print "Thursday"
    elif r == 5:
        print "Friday"
    elif r == 6:
        print "Sunday"

zeller =  Tkinter.Tk()
month_label = Tkinter.Label(zeller ,text="Write the month: ")
entry1 = Tkinter.Entry()
a = entry1.get()
date_label = Tkinter.Label(zeller, text="Enter the date: ")
entry2 =  Tkinter.Entry()
b = Entry2.get()
year_label = Tkinter.Label(zeller, text="Write the year: ")
entry3 = Tkinter.Entry()
c = Entry3.get()
button = Tkinter.Button(zeller, text = "Show the day",command = lambda:zellers(a,b,c) )
month_label.grid(row=0 , column=0)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=2)
date_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=2)
year_label.grid(row=3, column=0)
entry3.grid(row=3, column=2)
button.grid(row=4, column=1)
zeller.mainloop()
```

Comment: Evidently, that text box is empty when you call the function. Either that, or it is getting `A`, `B`, and `C` when you first instantiate the lambda and not when you actually call it. What you might need is to register a function with Tkinter. That might solve your problem.

Comment: What kind of fucntion do you mean ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was missing something. Don't worry about that thing I said before. `A`, `B`, and `C` are set to empty strings at the instant that the program starts, and they are never changed. What you want to do is change `lambda:zellers(A,B,C)` to `lambda:zellers(Entry1.get(), Entry2.get(), Entry3,get())`. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Yeah it also worked with that way.  "command = lambda:zellers(str(Entry1.get()), int(Entry2.get()), int(Entry3.get())"


Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calls to `get`

```
Entry1 = Tkinter.Entry()
A = Entry1.get()
```

query the Entry widgets immediately, right after creation. Since they are empty at that point, `A` (and `B` and `C`) are empty strings.
You need to call `get` *after* `zellers` gets called:

```
def zellers():
    A = Entry1.get()
    B = Entry2.get()
    C = Entry3.get()
    ...
```

---

```
import Tkinter

dictionary = {"March": 1, "April":2, "May":3, "June":4, "July":5,"August":6, 
              "September":7, "October":8, "November":9, "December":10 ,
              "January":11, "February":12}

def zellers():
    A = Entry1.get()
    B = Entry2.get()
    C = Entry3.get()

    D = int(str(C)[0:2])+1
    A = int(dictionary[A])
    B = int(B)
    C = int(str(C)[2:4])

    W = ((13*A)-1) / 5
    X = C / 4
    Y = D / 4
    Z = (W + X + Y + B + C) - 2*D
    R = Z%7
    result = {0: 'Sunday', 1: 'Monday', 2: 'Tuesday', 3: 'Wednesday', 4: 'Thursday', 
              5: 'Friday', 6: 'Saturday'}
    print(result[R])

root =  Tkinter.Tk()
month_label = Tkinter.Label(root ,text="Write the month: ")
Entry1 = Tkinter.Entry()
date_label = Tkinter.Label(root, text="Enter the date: ")
Entry2 =  Tkinter.Entry()
year_label = Tkinter.Label(root, text="Write the year: ")
Entry3 = Tkinter.Entry()
button = Tkinter.Button(root, text = "Show the day", command=zellers)

month_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
Entry1.grid(row=0, column=2)
date_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
Entry2.grid(row=1, column=2)
year_label.grid(row=3, column=0)
Entry3.grid(row=3, column=2)
button.grid(row=4, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yeah great it worked. Thanks a lot. What if I want the zellers function to have parameters ? I am just asking for curiosity

Comment: You can use a closure to make variables available to `zellers` at the time `zellers` is defined, or use a `lambda` (or regular function) to pass arguments to `zellers` at the time the button is pressed -- as [ddsnowboard suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213068/zellers-algorithm-with-tkinter-python/35213258?noredirect=1#comment58141760_35213068):  `lambda:zellers(Entry1.get(), Entry2.get(), Entry3,get())`. But remember that the function passed to the `command` parameter in `Tkinter.Button` can not take any arguments.